# Mongoose Populate Method for Querying

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two collections with one of the collections containing a linking field to make a relationship between the two collections. I am trying to figure out how to use the `populate` method correctly display documents from both collections that match my filter criteria.

Here is the setup for my two models.

Images

```
var imageSchema = new Schema({
    pattern: { type: String, enum: ['Solid', 'Stripe', 'Plaid'] },
    color: { type: String, enum: ['Grey', 'Navy Blue', 'Black', 'Khaki', 'Brown'] },
    imageName: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    imageSource: String,
    descriptions_id: String
});

var Images = mongoose.model('Images', imageSchema);

module.exports = Images;
```

Descriptions

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var descriptionSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    pattern: { type: String, enum: ['Solid', 'Stripe', 'Plaid'] },
    color: { type: String, enum: ['Grey', 'Navy Blue', 'Black', 'Khaki', 'Brown'] },
    body: String,
});

var Description = mongoose.model('Description', descriptionSchema);

module.exports = Description;
```

Basically I want to display all of the images that match my descriptions id value. For example I have a description that has the `_id` value of `navy-blue`. This value is the same as the `descriptions_id` value for image documents.

Would this be the appropriate command?

```
Images.find({ pattern: "solid", color:"navy-blue", descriptions_id:"navy-blue"}).populate('images').populate('descriptions');
```

**UPDATE:**

Example of Images and Descriptions document

Descriptions:

```
{
    "_id" : "navy-blue",
    "body" : "Lorem Impsum."
}
```

Images:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f5c6db7f057f0dfdfasdff2cf1cd"), "pattern" : "stripe", "propercasePattern" : "Stripe", "color" : "navy-blue", "propercaseColor" : "Navy Blue", "imageUrl" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/blue-shirt.jpg", "imageSource" : "source", "descriptions_id" : "navy-blue" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have optimize your schema. As you want to populate Description with images collections then why are you having same fields like pattern, color in both schema. if you want to populate then you have to give reference to descriptions collection when defining image schema.

```
var imageSchema = new Schema({
imageName: String,
imageUrl: String,
imageSource: String,
descriptions_id:{  type: Schema.ObjectId,
ref: 'Description'}
});
```

Then try with this query

```
 Images.find().populate({path:'descriptions_id',match:  {pattern:'solid',color:'navy-blue'}).exec(function(res){
 if(res){
   res = res.filter(function (doc) {
                    return doc.descriptions_id;
                });
         }
    })
```

Let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: thank you for your response. If I wanted to update my Images via the command line, how would I set the `descriptions_id`? For this example I have `_id` set in my Descriptions collection as `navy_blue` and in then updated all images that I wanted connected to that collection have an additional field `descriptions_id` set to `navy_blue`. Would this be the correct way to set it? I edited my answer to show an example of my Image document